# URLs and https?

Tags: html, url, https

Is it correct that when you use https, your URLs should start with `//[your-domain]/`
Someone (using WordPress I think) just told me that, but I can't find any precise info about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//[your-domain] means use https:// only if needed, if not use http://

Comment: Thank you. Something sounds ambiguous in your sentence (maybe because English is not my monther language maybe not). So '//[your-domain]' = https-only ? Or '//[your-domain]' = https-if-needed ?

Comment: Well it means if the page you are on is https. Consider a header in a website where in the head, a Javascript file is included. If the user is logged in over https the link will call https://linktolibrary.js but if a normal (not logged in) user visits the page it will call http://linktolibrary.js

Comment: But is it different from writing '/[your-path]' ?

Comment: If it is on your own server it works the same. But if you include scripts from a CDN like jquery form Google. Than // is http or https on the Google server where / means on your site root

Answer (score 2):

No, a URL that starts with `//` simply means that the protocol is the same as for the current page or, more generally, for the current base URL.

To use HTTPS, you need absolute URLs that start with `https://`, but you *may* use relative URLs that start with `//` to produce such absolute URLs. This is useful mainly if your HTML document may, depending on context, be accessed either with HTTP or with HTTPS (and you want a URL reference in it adapt to that).

Comment: But is it different from writing '/[your-path]' ?

Comment: @TTT, that’s a different issue, and should be asked as a separate question, if it is relevant. But please check first basic URL definitions; URLs that start with `//` are quite different from URLs that start with `/`.